# Remove like and reblog buttons from pages?

Tags: html, tumblr

I have a few custom pages on my tumblr, and with my theme, the like and reblog buttons appear anyway, even though those pages aren't posts. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2):

**Like / Reblog Buttons On Custom Pages**

The easiest way to prevent a like or reblog button appearing on a custom page is to wrap them in the `{block:Date}` theme operator.

Example:

```
{block:Date}
    {LikeButton}
    {ReblogButton}
{/block:Date}
```

Custom pages don't have a date, so the `{block:Date}` isn't rendered and the buttons don't appear.

Hope that helps!

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#dates

Answer (score -1):

right click the like/reblog buttons and then click inspect the reblog/like element you are looking at for each page.

go to edit your theme

find inspected elements in your theme

surround element with  `<block> </block>` tags

example:

`<block>`

INSPECTED ELEMENT

`</block>`

do the block tag for each element on each page

hope this works if not let me know and ill let you know a different way

Comment: Sorry, but this what is this?

Comment: mike: i thought this would work, it usually works for me

Comment: @mandrake In that case, its always best to use the correct syntax. `<block>` has no relation to Tumblr. If you revise the answer, it would be more helpful.